# Windows Equivalent to Linux: Find -name

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, command-prompt

I am trying to figure out a command in the CLI which I know in Linux Ubuntu but I need to apply it in Microsoft.

Moreover, I am trying to find all files within a folder with a specific name. Particularly, I try to find all files which contain the term 'test' in their name.
Here is the command which I know in Linux:

```
find \home\user\data -name '*test*'
```

Does anyone know the equivalent in the windows command line?

Comment: I believe all the previous answers are good options for Windows. In my case, I wanted to emulate the Linux command as accurate as possible to replicate my CI server environment. So, I found that good old find command is available for Windows, too. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will looking for **Get-ChildItem**

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Test -Filter "*test*"
```

Comment: You can add `-Recurse` to search in subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell you can use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) to find files and folders.

If you want to use regular expressions, you can combine `Get-ChildItem` with the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) or [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlets.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "Regex"
```

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.name -match "regex"}
```

Comment: The first one searches the contents of files, except for directory names.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the "dir" command. To accomplish the same thing as your original search, you would use

```
dir \home\user\data "*test*"
```

Comment: dir is an alias for `get-childitem`. `Get-Alias dir`

Answer (score 0):

Try find2.exe application
https://github.com/fernandoarbe/find2

```
cd \home\user\data
find2 test
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).